# React with Material-UI can't find module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to display a **Material** button with my **React** app, but I get this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@material-ui/core/styles/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/LumiereProject/lumiere_frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js' in '/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/LumiereProject/lumiere_frontend'
```

This is my `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import LoginModal from './components/Login';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <LoginModal />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And this is my module:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

class LoginModal extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Button variant="contained" className="{classes.Button}">
          Welcome to Lumiere...
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginModal;
```

Everything works fine, until I try to use **Material** components in my app. Maybe I am missing to install something, but the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/#cdn) I am following doesn't requiere anything in particular.

Comment: Can you show your imports for your `LoginModal`?

Comment: @ic3b3rg I added it.

Comment: imports look good - try reinstalling your modules

Comment: Run NPM i for the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the error message, it says that the module it can't find is babel-loader ('/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/LumiereProject/lumiere_frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/**babel-loader**/lib/index.js').

Try running `npm install --save babel-loader` and compile again. If that doesn't work, try reinstalling all dependencies `npm ci` and compile again.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. I installed Material-UI while my development server was still running. Restarting the server did the trick. I've noticed some packages don't "kick in" until you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the server solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I simply ran `yarn add @material-ui/core -D` for npm you would run `npm install @material-ui/core --save-dev`

Im running react 18.2 as of this writing ive upgraded my entire FE stack i.e  react, typescript, tailwind, mui and webpack all running on the latest version.

Heres my package.json if you want a quick reference copy pasta

```json
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.17.12",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.2",
    "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",
    "@inertiajs/inertia-react": "^0.8.0",
    "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.1",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.77",
    "@mui/material": "^5.6.1",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.9.0",
    "@npmcli/ci-detect": "^2.0.0",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.0-rc.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@tsconfig/recommended": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.30.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.29.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.9",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draft-js-export-html": "^1.4.1",
    "draft-js-import-html": "^1.4.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-tailwindcss": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^43.0.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "^3.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "mui-rte": "^2.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
    "prettier": "^2.7.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
    "stylus": "^0.58.1",
    "stylus-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.4",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
    "tsc": "^2.0.4",
    "tscheck": "^0.1.5",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3",
    "watchexec-bin": "^1.0.0",
    "zod": "^3.17.3"
  },
```